# Can move or copy document library views from one library to another library in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, list-view

Can move or copy document library views from one library to another library in SharePoint. Any tool for use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no a direct way to do that but I think no need to use a tool if you applied the below workaround:

- Save the document library (that has the views) as a template **without** include content,

[image]

- Then create a new document library from this template.
- Then move the documents from the old doc library that does not have views to the new one that already created by opening both documents libraries `with explorer` then copy and paste the documents from the source to the destination.

[image]

In case of the `Open with explorer` is disabled check [We’re having a problem opening this location in File Explorer, Add this web site to your Trusted sites list and try again](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/23/were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/)